# Debugging pagination with Paging Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

So I wrote a simple notes functionality with the paging library using `LiveData` and Room database but I don't see it actually paginating anything. Perhaps I am not debugging correctly to confirm that pagination is happening. Any advice is appreciated.

In my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id ASC")
fun allNotes(): DataSource.Factory<Int, NoteEntity>
```

Then in my `NotesRepository`, I convert from `NoteEntity` to `Note` to keep my data layer implementation detail and the rest of the app separate (I am a fan of Clean Architecture). So the result is `DataSource.Factory<Int, Note>`:

```
override fun allNotes(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Note> =
        notesDao.allNotes().map { mapper.fromDb(it) }
```

In my `ViewModel` where `PAGE_SIZE` is 20:

```
val noteList: LiveData<PagedList<Note>> =
        LivePagedListBuilder(
                getNotesUseCase.allNotes(), PAGE_SIZE)
```

My `Note` is simply:

```
data class Note(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val text: String
)
```

Then I am displaying the notes in `RecyclerView`.

My `ViewHolder` contains:

```
class NoteViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false))  {
   private val idView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteId)
   private val nameView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteText)
   private var note: Note? = null

   /**
    * Items might be null if they are not paged in yet. PagedListAdapter will re-bind the
    * ViewHolder when Item is loaded.
    */
    fun bindTo(note: Note?) {
        this.note = note
        idView.text = note?.let { it.id.toString() } ?: ""
        nameView.text = note?.text ?: ""
    }
}
```

My `Adapter` contains:

```
class NoteAdapter(
    private val clickListener: ClickListener) : PagedListAdapter<Note, NoteViewHolder>(diffCallback) {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Timber.d("Binding view holder at position $position")
    val note = getItem(position)

    with(holder) {
        bindTo(note)
        note?.let {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(note)
        }
    }
}

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder =
        NoteViewHolder(parent)

companion object {
    /**
     * This diff callback informs the PagedListAdapter how to compute list differences when new
     * PagedLists arrive.
     */
    private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Note>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Note, newItem: Note): Boolean =
                oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Note, newItem: Note): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

And my `Fragment` contains:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setupRecyclerView()

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, noteListViewModelFactory).get(NoteListViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.noteList.observe(this, Observer { pagedNoteList ->
        pagedNoteList?.let { render(pagedNoteList) }
    })
}

private fun render(pagedNoteList: PagedList<Note>) {
    recyclerViewAdapter.submitList(pagedNoteList)
}
```

The data in the RecyclerView is loaded successfully and I see the debug logs when each item is bound. **My understanding is `PagedListAdapter` I use requests new pages as the user scrolls and handles the new `PagedList`s by computing differences on a background thread.**

My data source contains 100 items so I would expect that with page size of 20, there are 5 calls made for data when a testing on an average size phone.

How do I debug this to ensure the correct number of calls? Also, in the implementation above, is one of these being used by default (PositionalDataSource, ItemKeyedDataSource or PageKeyedDataSource)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It appears that in Room `PositionalDataSource` is being used by default.

I was able to figure out how my Notes are being loaded in chunks by adding the following log statement inside my `NoteAdapter.onBindViewHolder()`:

```
Log.d("NoteAdapter", currentList)
```

where `currentList` is a property of the super class `PagedListAdapter`.

```
/**
 * Returns the PagedList currently being displayed by the Adapter.
 * etc.
 */
@Nullable
public PagedList<T> getCurrentList() {
    return mDiffer.getCurrentList();
}
```

As user scrolls, new items are bound to view holder and the log shows the contents of the `currentList` that's being iterated over.

Also note that when you set the page size to `N`, initial list size will contain a count of `3 * N`. Then each time user scrolls thru them all, `N` more items will be put into `currentList`. This is because I used the default configuration when requesting page list:

```
val noteList: LiveData<PagedList<Note>> =
        LivePagedListBuilder(
                getNotesUseCase.allNotes(), PAGE_SIZE)
                .build()
```

Instead, I could have done something like this to control initialLoadSizeHint:

```
private val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE)
        .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
        .build()

val noteList = LivePagedListBuilder<Int,Note>(getNotesUseCase.allNotes(), pagedListConfig).build()
```

By default, **initialLoadSizeHint** equals PAGE_SIZE * 3.